# How to unload kernel modules

Tags: kernel, kernel-extensions

When I run `kextstat`, it gives me a list of the currently loaded kernel modules. How to I go about using the information gathered from this command to unload a kernel module?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can unload kernel modules with `kextunload` either specifying the whole path to the kernel extension as a parameter (they reside in `/System/Library/Extensions/`) or by specifying the bundle identifier displayed by `kextstat`, e.g. if you want to unload Fuse for OS X:

```
sudo kextunload -b com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfusefs
```

You can then use `kextload` for loading extension in the same way.

**Bonus hint:** If you only want to see 3rd party kernel extensions that aren’t from Apple you can use inverse grep:

```
kextstat | grep -v com.apple
```